# rewindDirectory()を実行してもファイルが先頭に戻らない。

Tags: spresense

開発環境はArduinoです。

以下のようなプログラムを実行させましたが、 `rewindDirectory()` 実行後、2度目のファイル名取得をスルーしました。
なにか間違えていますでしょうか？
或いは、SDカードに依存した現象でしょうか？
ご教示ください。

また、認識できたファイル数が9個まで（実際は13個のファイルが存在する）となります。
ファイル数に制限がありますか？

```c
//For SPRESENSE
#include <SDHCI.h>
SDClass SD;
const uint8_t cs_SD = 5;

char Mp3Name[128];

File theSD;
File entry;
File root;
void setup()
{
int nk = 0;
Serial.begin(115200);
SD.begin();

// SDカードのファイル名取得の実験
root = SD.open("/");
while (true)
{
entry = root.openNextFile();
if (!entry)
{
//これ以上ファイルがない場合
root.rewindDirectory();
usleep(40000);
break;
}

    //ディレクトリ名ではない場合
    if (!entry.isDirectory()) 
    {
        String fileName = entry.name();
        strcpy(Mp3Name, &fileName[0]);
        nk++;
        printf("[%02d] %s\n", nk, Mp3Name);
    }
}
nk = 0;
while (true) 
{
    entry = root.openNextFile();
    if (!entry)
    {
        //これ以上ファイルがない場合
        root.rewindDirectory();
        usleep(40000);
        break;
    }

    //ディレクトリ名ではない場合
    if (!entry.isDirectory()) 
    {
        String fileName = entry.name();
        strcpy(Mp3Name, &fileName[0]);
        nk++;
        printf("[%02d] %s\n", nk, Mp3Name);
    }
}
printf("SetupEnd\n");

}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Answer (score 2):

同じ問題にハマったことがあります。

`File entry = dir.openNextFile();` の最後に、`entry.close();` でファイルをクローズすれば動くと思います。きっと open できるファイル数の上限か何かに引っ掛かっているのだと思います（予想）

SDHCIのサンプルスケッチ UsbMscAndFileOperation.ino はどうして動くんだろうと思って差分を眺めていて気がつきました。

試してみてください。

```c
//For SPRESENSE
#include <SDHCI.h>
SDClass SD;
const uint8_t cs_SD = 5;

char Mp3Name[128];

File theSD;
File entry;
File root;
void setup()
{
  int nk = 0;
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SD.begin();

  // SDカードのファイル名取得の実験
  root = SD.open("/");
  while (true)
    {
      entry = root.openNextFile();
      if (!entry)
        {
          //これ以上ファイルがない場合
          root.rewindDirectory();
          usleep(40000);
          break;
        }

      //ディレクトリ名ではない場合
      if (!entry.isDirectory())
        {
          String fileName = entry.name();
          strcpy(Mp3Name, &fileName[0]);
          nk++;
          printf("[%02d] %s\n", nk, Mp3Name);
        }
      entry.close(); // ★★追加★★
    }
  nk = 0;
  while (true)
    {
      entry = root.openNextFile();
      if (!entry)
        {
          //これ以上ファイルがない場合
          root.rewindDirectory();
          usleep(40000);
          break;
        }

      //ディレクトリ名ではない場合
      if (!entry.isDirectory())
        {
          String fileName = entry.name();
          strcpy(Mp3Name, &fileName[0]);
          nk++;
          printf("[%02d] %s\n", nk, Mp3Name);
        }
      entry.close(); // ★★追加★★
    }
  printf("SetupEnd\n");

}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
正直まだ期待通りの結果は得られいませんが、教えていただいたサンプル
を行く見てみてみます。

Comment: 期待動作が分かりませんが、もしディレクトリ内のファイル名まで取得したい場合は、entry.close() の追加は必要ですが、http://www.musashinodenpa.com/arduino/ref/index.php?f=1&pos=1965 を参考に再帰呼び出しにする必要があります。

Comment: 多忙でこの板をよく見れていませんでした。
 entry.close(); // ★★追加★★　
これが決定的だったのですね。
自分でも（これを見る前に）先ほど気が付ついて、先頭に戻ることを確認できました。

再帰呼び出しによるサブディレクトリ内部のファイル名取得は、了解です。
みなさんありがとうございました。